# How can I set text Area properties inside controller page using ROR

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Can anyone resolve my small issue ?Actually i want to set Text Area enable after the page is loading and some condition checked.Let me to explain my story actually what i want.

Story:

I have a blog page .When user will be logged in and enter into the blog page then the text area should be enabled to do the comments.If user will directly get into the blog page to write the comment it will show the disabled until unless the user has not logged in.

My code snippets are as follows.

views/person/index.html.erb:

```
<div class="photo">
</div>
<div class="main-div">
<ul>
<li>HOME</li>
<a href="/persons/new"><li>SIGN UP</li></a>
<a href="/persons/login"><li>LOGIN</li></a>
<a href="/persons/myblog"><li>MY BLOG</li></a>
<li>CONTENT</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

views/person/login.html.erb:

```
<div class="login-div">
<%= form_for :person,:url =>{:controller =>"sessions",:action => "logincreate"} do |f| %>
<%= f.email_field :email,:class => "email_field",placeholder:"Enter your email" %><%= f.password_field :password,:class => "email_field",placeholder:"Enter your password" %><%= f.submit "LogIn",:class => "btn-div" %>
<% end %>
</div>
<div class="message">
    <% if flash[:color]== "valid" %>
        <div class="success">
            <p><%= flash[:notice]%></p>
        </div>
    <% elsif flash[:color]== "invalid"%>
        <div class="error">
            <p><%=flash[:notice]%></p>
        </div>
    <%else%>
        <div class="notice">
            <p><%=flash[:notice]%></p>
        </div>
    <%end%>
</div>
<div class="message"> 
    <% if @person.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@person.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @person.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

views/person/myblog.html.erb

```
    <div class="navigation">
<textarea id="text" style="width:400px; height:120px" placeholder="Type your comment here" disabled ></textarea>
</div>
<button type="button" id="btn" class="btn-div" >Comment</button>
<section class="maindrop">

<div class="wrapper-demo">
    <div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-2" tabindex="1">Sign in with
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li><a href="/persons/login">Login in Website</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Google</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
<div class="message">
    <% if flash[:color]== "valid" %>
        <div class="success">
            <p><%= flash[:notice]%></p>
        </div>
    <% elsif flash[:color]== "invalid"%>
        <div class="error">
            <p><%=flash[:notice]%></p>
        </div>
    <%else%>
        <div class="notice">
            <p><%=flash[:notice]%></p>
        </div>
    <%end%>
</div>
<div class="message"> 
    <% if @person.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@person.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @person.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

controller/persons_controller.rb

```
  class PersonsController < ApplicationController
    def index

    end
    def new
        @person=Person.new
    end
    def login
        @person=Person.new
    end
    def myblog

    end
    def create
        @person=Person.new(params[:person])
        if @person.save
            flash[:notice]="User has created successfully.."
            flash[:color]="valid"
            redirect_to :action => 'index'
        else
            flash[:notice]="User could not create.."
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'new'
        end
    end

end


controller/sessions_controller.rb

class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    def logincreate
        @person=Person.find_by_email(params[:person][:email])
        session[:userid]=@user.id
        if @person.password==params[:person][:password]
            flash[:notice]="User has logeed in"
            flash[:color]="valid"
            redirect_to :action => "myblog"
        else
            flash[:notice]="logeed in failed"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'login'
    end
end
```

If any has any solution regarding this issue Please share with .Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do to make this work -

in `ApplicationController`:

```
helper_method :current_person, :person_logged_in?

def authenticate_user!
  redirect_to login_persons_path, alert: 'Please login to continue.' unless user_logged_in? # replace login_persons_path with the correct login route path
end

def current_person
  @current_person ||= Person.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
end

def person_logged_in?
  !!current_person
end
```

in your myblog.html.erb:

```
<textarea id="text" style="width:400px; height:120px" placeholder="Type your comment here" <%= person_logged_in? ? 'disabled' : '' %> ></textarea>
```

Use `authenticate_user!` method in other controllers for `before_filter` to check if user is logged in or not and to redirect them to login page if they're not.